# Computing the efficiency in percentage between two times in Excel

Tags: excel, formula, calculated-columns

I got in Excel  two cells of type  "hh:mm:ss" and I need to find how fast was the first column from the second column in percentage.
Is there any simple way to find that ?
Thanks!

Comment: I read this as meaning the times are durations, e.g. car x takes 01:01:01 to finish; car y takes 02:02:02. If that's the case then just divide one cell by the other and change to percentage format, i.e. x / y = 50%. ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need to have a some sort of baseline to which to compare the time difference.  For example, "how fast" is 100% efficient?

The formula is straight-forward:

```
(t2 - t1) / baseline
```

where, (t2-t1) is in the same units as baseline.